# Convert hex character inside a string to a character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a raw HTTP response that I got from requests
Part of the response are

```
<INPUT type='hidden' name=WdsMode1   ID=WdsMode1 value=''>
<script language=javascript>Transfer_meaning('WdsMode1','WDS\x5fDisable');</script>
```

I then used regex to take two parts of the response above

```
re.findall(r'>Transfer_meaning\(\'(.*?)\',\'(.*?)\'\)', response.text)
```

The second group that RegEx returns is `WDS\x5fDisable`. I want to parse it and convert the hex character in that string so it will be `WDS_Disable`.
How can this be done in Python?
TLDR: The string contains a hex character `\x5f`. How do i convert it to a text `_`

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-string-from-hex-to-ascii-in-python#:~:text=Use%20bytes.,0x%22%20from%20a%20hexadecimal%20string. for converting hex to ascii

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this:

```py
>>>chr(ord('\x5f'))
'_'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using:

```
string.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
```

as mine contains double backslashes